# How can I combine rows and separate the different values with a comma?

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I want to combine the rows and separate distinct entries by a comma.
I tried the following. Starting from

```
    Postcode    Borough         Neighbourhood
    M3A         North York      Parkwoods
    M3A         North York      Victoria Village
```

I typed in the following command

```
df.groupby(['Postcode','Borough'])["Neighbourhood"].apply(lambda item:', '.join(item)
```

But that gives me

```
                                            Neighbourhood
            Postcode    Borough         
            M3A         North York          Parkwoods, Victoria Village
```

The problem is that the last column is somehow 'above' all the others. Can''t I do this in a way that retains the old column structure?
Thanks!

Comment: Use `reset_index` after, or specify `as_index=False` in `groupby`.

Comment: i tried doing ```as_index=False``` in ```groupby```, but i got almost the same result, the only difference being that now over the last column it says ```0``` instead of ```Neighborhoods```. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: I suggest using your existing code, but use reset_index(name="Neighbourhood") after that.